# How to lazy load a route as a child route/component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular2-routing

Let's take a look at my plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/22RIoGsvzfw2y2ZTnazg?p=preview

I want to lazy load a Module as a child-route.

So the route `/lazy` should render the  `LazyModule` into the `<router-outlet>` of my `MainComponent`.

Then it will switch between that `DummyComponent` and the lazy loaded Module.

Instead now that lazy loaded Module will be rendered into the `AppComponent`..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to lazy load a module, do not import it as you've done here :

**src/app.ts** :

```
import { LazyModule } from './lazy/lazy.module';
...

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), LazyModule ]
```

If you load a module (using `import`) it will be bundled into the main module instead of having a separated chunk.

Replace it by :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ]
```

Then your routes should be like that :

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: DummyComponent
      },
      // should be rendered as a CHILD of my MainComponent .. !!
      {
        path: 'lazy',
        loadChildren: 'src/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Notice that `loadChildren` path starts from `src` now.

---

For **src/lazy/lazy.module.ts** :
You should have your routes defined (as it's needed for children modules) **BUT** your routes should be empty because they'll be suffixed by their parent's routes. (here : '/lazy').

So if you put :

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'lazy',
    component: LazyComponent
  }
];
```

You expect to match `/lazy/lazy` to use your lazy component, which is not what you want.

Instead use :

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LazyComponent
  }
]
```

Here's the working Plunkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/KdqKLokuAXcp5qecLslH?p=preview

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! :)

Comment: Made my day! Also checkout reducing your angular production bundle size in the first answer by jgodi here [How to reduce bundle size](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9016)

Comment: What if in the Lazy module's route, I already have another component mapped to the empty path '' and do not want to change that ?