# ERROR while adding custom module to parent app module in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to add new module to make my angular application more modular and for lazy loading.

**app.module**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule,BrowserXhr } from "@angular/http";
import { LabService } from './lab/lab.service';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { OphistoryModule } from './Ophistory/ophistory.Module' //after adding this module ERROR is thrown

@NgModule({
  imports:[ 
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: 'labDetails/:labName',component:LabDetailsComponent},
      {path:'showRoboLog/:labName',component:RoboLogComponent},
      {path:'',component:LabComponent}
    ]),
   OphistoryModule
 ],
 declarations: [ 
   AppComponent
 ],
 bootstrap:[ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { LabComponent } from './lab/lab.component';

import { LabService } from './lab/lab.service';

@Component({

  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,

  providers: [LabService]

})

export class AppComponent { 

  constructor() {
  }

  pageTitle: string = 'ABC';
}
```

The problem I am facing after adding the module **OphistoryModule** is an error message saying

> my-app' is not a known element:

But when I give the same name to the selector of my newly added module it is working fine.
Here are the custom module and component

**ophistory.module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { OphistoryComponent } from './ophistory.component'
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common'
@NgModule({ 
imports: [RouterModule.forChild([
   {path: 'test',component:OphistoryComponent}
]),CommonModule],
  declarations:[OphistoryComponent]
})
export class OphistoryModule {}
```

**ophistory.component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { LabService } from '../lab/lab.service'

@Component({
  selector:'my-ap',
  templateUrl:'./ophistory.component.html'
})
export class OphistoryComponent {
  constructor (private _service:LabService){}
}
```

Can anyone confirm if it is a bug in angular 2 or any other solution you have?

Comment: It certainly not a bug on Angular side... I don't see the import for OphistoryComponentTest

Comment: sorry it was a typo.I tried to remove unwanted details so by mistake i forgot to remove this

Comment: I don't see CommunModule imported

Comment: importing CommonModule is necessary ?

Comment: I have imported CommonModule to ophistory.module  but still the same ERROR.Strange part is if i change the selector of ophistory.component to my-app(same as in main app.component )then no ERROR is throwing.

Comment: where are the routes for the ophistory module?

Comment: @Vega  Please check my updated question

Comment: sorry to say but i fogot to add this in stackoverflow but in actual code i have already imported it.My visual studio code is taking care of those imports so i forgot to add in here

Comment: I think routes need to be redefined, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799478/how-to-lazy-load-a-route-as-a-child-route-component

Comment: still same error.