# Component not loaded into router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router, router-outlet

When

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
```

and

```
<router-outlet name="buildingDetails"></router-outlet>
```

are in the same template **app.component.html**, a click on Building Details Button will load **BuildingDetailsComponent** into the *buildingDetails router-outlet*.

But when comment out *buildingDetails router-outlet* in **app.component.html** and comment in *buildingDetails router-outlet* in **sidenavigation.component.html**, BuildingDetailsComponent will not be loaded into *buildingDetails router-outlet* on Building Details Button Click anymore.

app.component.html:

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="buildingDetails"></router-outlet>
```

sidenavigation.component.html:

```
<p>
  sidenavigation works!
</p>
<button (click)="openBuildingDetails()">
  Building Details
</button>
<hr>
<!--<router-outlet name="buildingDetails"></router-outlet>--> when moving the router outlet here, loading BuildingDetails Component on openBuildingDetails() button click is not working anymore
```

sidenavigation.component.ts:

`public openBuildingDetails() {
    this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { buildingDetails: "feature-component" } }]);
  }`

app-routing-module:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",
    component: SidenavigationComponent,
    pathMatch: "full"
},
{
    path: "feature-component",
    loadChildren: "./modules/building/building.module#BuildingModule",
    outlet: "buildingDetails"
}];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
        appRoutes,
        {
            enableTracing: true
        }
    )
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
]})
```

building-routing-module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: "",
    component: BuildingDetailsComponent
}];

@NgModule({
imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
],
exports: [
    RouterModule
]})
```

Does anybody know why and how this can be solved?

I added a code example for each case. The only difference between both examples is the location of the named router-outlet. The first one is working (named router-outlet is in app.component.html). The second one is not working (named router-outlet is in sidenavigation.html).

Desired Behavior: BuildingDetails Component should also be loaded when the named  router-outlet is in a different location than the first unnamed router-outlet.

Problem: When moving the named router-outlet into a different template than the unnamed router-outlet, BuildingDetails Component is not loading anymore on openBuildingDetails() button click.

Working: https://stackblitz.com/github/stonedraider/router-outlets

Not working: https://stackblitz.com/github/stonedraider/not-working-router-outlets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add side navigation selector in app.component.html as below and remove parent router-outlet because of parent router-outlet conflicts while loading component.

```
<app-sidenavigation></app-sidenavigation>
```

and now the side navigation component loads building component.

Either refer below answer link to load children with lazy load:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799478/how-to-lazy-load-a-route-as-a-child-route-component)

Comment: I want the navigation to work also with the router-outlet in sidenavigation.component.html which is <router-outlet name="buildingDetails"></router-outlet>, and not only when it is in app.component.html

Comment: then you can add another router-outlet in it and define routing in child level in that module otherwise please give more detail or add proper demo.

Comment: Can you explain why the parent router-outlet conflicts while loading the component? In the project that I'm working on it seems to be necessary, that app-sidenavigation is being loaded through a router-outlet as well, so I don't think that I can replace the router-outlet by inserting app-sidenavigation with its html-tag.

Comment: Actually your parent routes in app.module refer then you can see lazy load is different path not as children part like path: '', children:[] but it is as base route so any case it will refer parent router-outlet.

Comment: Okay, so the way to go would be to just move the lazy load route to children:[] of sidenavigation path? When I do it throws the error "Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'feature-component'" when clicking on BuildingDetails button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40799478/how-to-lazy-load-a-route-as-a-child-route-component follow this link

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your help my friend!

Comment: Please upvote for help you as invested lots of time :) I updated the answer!

Comment: Yeah I tried to upvote but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."